# Uncertainty of energy for harmonic oscillator at ground state and first excited state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

How does one calculate the energy uncertainty of the harmonic oscillator in the ground state and first excited state?

Comment: Have you consulted a book or tried anything your self? We do not answer questions like this unless the asker demonstrates effort.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in the ground state (which is an energy eigenstate) or if it is in the first excited state (which is also an energy eigenstate) or if is is in *any* energy eigenstate... then the "energy uncertainty" is exactly zero.

Zero. Yes, zero.

Did I stutter? No, I didn't. So you heard me.